# Determine equation of the tangent to the curve y=e^-x at x=-1

Tags: calculus

I need to determine the equation of the tangent to the curve y=e^-x at the point where x=-1.

The answer in the book is ex+y=0 but I don't understand how to get this answer.

I found the derivative as y'=-e^-x, buy I  don't know what to do from here.

Comment: The equation of the tangent line at $x_0$ is $y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f(x_0)$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}$. So $f'(x)=-e^{-x}$.

The slope of the tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x=-1$ would be $f'(-1)=-e$.

Let the tangent line at $x=-1$ be $y=ax+b$.

Since the slope of the line is $-e$, $a=-e$.

When $x=-1,f(x)=f(-1)=e$. Then we can plug in point $(-1,e)$ into the equation $y=-ex+b$ and solve for $b$.

$e=e+b \Rightarrow b=0$

Therefore, the tangent line at $x=-1$ would be $y=-ex$

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up. I also tried the y=ax+b but I was getting nowhere because I kept forgetting the - sign on 1 when substituting it in for x.